# How to index a table with a Type 2 slowly changing dimension for optimal performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing, data-warehouse

Suppose you have a table with a Type 2 slowly-changing dimension.

Let's express this table as follows, with the following columns:

```
* [Key]
* [Value1]
* ...
* [ValueN]
* [StartDate]
* [ExpiryDate]
```

In this example, let's suppose that [StartDate] is effectively the date in which the values for a given [Key] become known to the system.  So our primary key would be composed of both [StartDate] and [Key].

When a new set of values arrives for a given [Key], we assign [ExpiryDate] to some pre-defined high surrogate value such as '12/31/9999'.  We then set the existing "most recent" records for that [Key] to have an [ExpiryDate] that is equal to the [StartDate] of the new value.  A simple update based on a join.

---

So if we always wanted to get the most recent records for a given [Key], we know we could create a clustered index that is:

```
* [ExpiryDate] ASC
* [Key] ASC
```

Although the keyspace may be very wide (say, a million keys), we can minimize the number of pages between reads by initially ordering them by [ExpiryDate].  And since we know the most recent record for a given key will always have an [ExpiryDate] of '12/31/9999', we can use that to our advantage.

However... what if we want to get a point-in-time snapshot of all [Key]s at a given time?  Theoretically, the entirety of the keyspace isn't all being updated at the same time.  Therefore for a given point-in-time, the window between [StartDate] and [ExpiryDate] is variable, so ordering by either [StartDate] or [ExpiryDate] would never yield a result in which all the records you're looking for are contiguous.  Granted, you can immediately throw out all records in which the [StartDate] is greater than your defined point-in-time.

---

In essence, in a typical RDBMS, what indexing strategy affords the best way to minimize the number of reads to retrieve the values for all keys for a given point-in-time?  I realize I can at least maximize IO by partitioning the table by [Key], however this certainly isn't ideal.

Alternatively, is there a different type of slowly-changing-dimension that solves this problem in a more performant manner?

Comment: Are you using Analysis Services?

Answer (score 1):

Lazy DBA

Are you talking about bringing back all the values in your dimension table?  If so, then why not add a non-clustered index with additional coverage such that you're only pulling values out of the index itself, rather than from the table?  That way you're scanning a B-Tree with some attached "covered" values, as opposed to potentially performing a table scan?  I can't vouch for relative performance, but it's worth testing for the scenario you're obviously working on.

Cheers

Ozziemedes
http://ozziemedes.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

If this is truly a "slowly changing dimension" table, I would consider a clustered columnstore index. I know this wasn't available when you asked the question, but anyway. you'll find some great documentation here:
"https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx"
and here
"http://www.nikoport.com/2013/07/05/clustered-columnstore-indexes-part-1-intro/".

now if you want to stick to rowstore indexes, if you're inserting the data in table sequentially, what I've done in the past was leveraging an identity field. your queries would be something like:

```
    declare @id;
    select @id = min(ID) from table where date = '12/31/9999';
    select fields from table where key = 112 and id > @id;
```